# Magento 1.9 CE: configurable products stock alert

Tags: configurable-product, stock, alert

I sell t-shirts (configurable products) in three sizes (simple products).

I have set: *System > Configuration > Catalog > Allow Alert When Product Comes Back in Stock - Yes*

I have a simple product (Red T-shirt, size S) with 0 items (no stock), and the product page shows *"Sign up to get notified when product is back in stock"*. That is ok.

But **I want the notification alert link** ("Sign up to get notified when this product is back in stock") **to be displayed in the configurable product page** (Red T-shirt page) **if ANY of the simple products related to the configurable product (any of the sizes) is out of stock.**

Is this even possible?

I am new to Magento, kind of lost here. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If some individually products are out of stock they won't be listed in frontend. Back in stock notification works only when the product which joins all simple/individual products in one will be out of stock. You can check by yourself what is happening when product is out of stock and you add an alert for it in product_alert_stock table.